Create dictionay in c#
I came across the below code but could not understand what the writer try to do here
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    [Literals.Date] = Literals.Date,
    [Literals.OperationType] = Literals.OperationType,
    [Literals.AuditDetail] = Literals.AuditDetail,
    [Literals.OperationCode] = Literals.OperationCode,
    [Literals.MainChannelCode] = Literals.MainChannelCode,
    [Literals.UpperChannelCode] = Literals.UpperChannelCode,
    [Literals.ChannelCode] = Literals.ChannelCode,
    [Literals.CoefficientOldValue] = Literals.CoefficientOldValue,
    [Literals.Coefficient] = Literals.Coefficient
};

Literals.Date is defined like that:
 public static string Date => "Date";

What is the meaning of this code? What does [ ] operator do in this usage?
I tested the usage but it does not make sense to me. The key and value looks the same in the dictionary. This usage is all over the company's repository so I think there is a reason for creating dictionary like that.


Its just a dictionary initilization syntax: initialize a C# dictionary

Keys and values being the same is just a way of (probably) having a dictionary lookup to find the strings using a hash algorithm (fast lookup) ... might be other ways to do that though (it does seem kind of weird ... if you have the key then you don't really need to get the value anymore, since they are the same. But you would have the extra feature of testing if such a key "exists").

It's bonkers. A List<string> would achieve the same thing. "This usage is all over the company's repository" - do you have an example of where it's called/used? I honestly can't think of a good reason for this idiom.

@iakobski: A List<string> is effectively an array under the covers. Looking up a value is an O(N) operation. A Dictionary<string, string> lookup is O(1). But, if you have 9 entries in the collection, who cares

@Flydog57 yes that is true, but if the key is the same as the value, you don't have to look up at all, just use the key directly! The only possible use I can think of is if you need to find the index for a given string, but there are better ways of doing that.
